# How to find the longest stem for a stem-loop in DNA

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to find the longest stem in the stem loop of DNA sequence. Here is code I have so far. Can someone please help? I am new to python and trying to practice few exercises.

```
basepairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}

listDNA = 'ATGGGCAT'
listREV = listDNA[::-1]

stem = ''
for i in range(len(listDNA)):
    for j in range(len(listDNA)):
       if listDNA[i] == basepairs[listREV[j]]:
           stem += listDNA[j]
       else:
           break

print stem
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you mean by this. What *is* the longest stem?  What is the desired output? What output do you get instead?

Comment: What is the result expected for the example?

Comment: Are you trying to find the longest strand of the form XYZ where Z is the reverse-complement of X? If so, are there any constraints on Y?

Comment: Stem-loops occur when two regions of the same DNA strand, complementary in base sequence when read in opposite directions, base-pair to form a double helix that ends in an unpaired loop. The online tool to check your DNA sequence for loops/check your code for correctness: http://unafold.rna.albany.edu/?q=mfold (Links to an external site.)

Comment: The expected result for the short example sequence in the input is ATG because that is the ONLY complementary sequence that will form stem-loop, but in longer sequences there maybe more stem-loops of varying lengths.

Comment: You should edit your question so that it includes the needed information, in terms that a programmer can understand. Don't assume that your reader knows what all this terminology means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took [example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stem-loop#Structural_contexts). Also took into account the strain cannot overlap itself. Or it can?

```
basepairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}

listDNA = 'GACACGGTGCAACTTAGCACCGTGCA'
listREV = listDNA[::-1]

longest_stem = ''
longest_match = ''
for i in range(len(listDNA)):
    #print('i = {}'.format(i))
    # forward strain order
    for strain_start in range(len(listDNA)):
       #print(' start = {}'.format(strain_start))
       stem = ''
       match = ''
       # stem cannot overlap with itself
       for n in range( (len(listDNA) - i - strain_start) / 2):
           if listDNA[i+n] == basepairs[listREV[i+n]]:
               #print('  added = {}'.format(listDNA[i+n]))
               stem += listDNA[i+n]
               match += listREV[i+n]
           else:
               break
       if len(stem) > len(longest_stem):
            longest_stem = stem
            longest_match = match

print longest_stem
print longest_match
```

Output:

```
CACGGTGC
GTGCCACG
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat compact version that starts which exploits the observation that once you reach a length with the property that no sub-strand of that length has its reverse complement somewhere else, then it is pointless to look at even larger lengths:

```
basepairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}

def reverseComplement(s):
    return ''.join(basepairs[b] for b in s[::-1])

def longestStem(s):
    n = len(s)
    k = int(n/2) #length of longest possible stem
    candidate = ''
    i = 1

    while i <= k and len(candidate) == i - 1:
        for j in xrange(n-2*i+1):
            t = s[j:i+j]
            if reverseComplement(t) in s[i+j:]:
                candidate = t
                break
        i +=1
    return candidate
```

It works with your sample, and can also handle things like this reasonably quick:

```
import random
s = ''.join(random.choice('ATGC') for i in range(10**4))
print longestStem(s)
```

But once the strands get much longer, you would need to switch to something more sophisticated. Perhaps a dictionary-based approach to get rid of the `O(n)` factor hidden in the `in` operator. Perhaps a depth-first search to fathom the tree that is implicitly formed by the stems.